# phonegap Android send email without going to Mail composer

Tags: android, email, cordova

In my android phone-gap application, i am trying to achieve send mail without opening mail composer.

how can i achieve this functionality, After googling i found there are some native solutions but there are no plugins for this type of mail sending.

please help on this matter.

a little help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are most likely going to need to implement a PhoneGap plugin, if there is not already one for this.